# Make Windows hard drive invisible to linux

Tags: hard-drive

I have two solid state HDDs in my computer: one with Windows10 and the other one with Linux. The Windows OS does not see the second HDD (with Linux), because I deallocated it before installing Linux. I also want the Linux OS to not see the fist HDD on which Windows is installed. This is just to make sure that users of one OS could not corrupt the files of the other OS.

What is the proper way to make the HDD with WindowsOS invisible/inaccessible to the LinuxOS that is being run from the other HDD?

Comment: 1) You could uninstall package `ntfs-3g`, so your Linux is not able to mount ntfs filesystems. This also means that you disable _all_ ntfs partitions from being mounted. 2) If you only want to disable users to access the windows partitions, you might add entries in `/etc/fstab` for those partitions with the options `noauto,nouser`, so only root can mount them. 3) If you want to disable access from linux to the Windows HDD in general, remove that HDD.

Comment: What kind of other users are there? Can they run `sudo` to get elevated permissions? The 'best' method to make a drive invisible depends on this, so please tell us.

Comment: @sudodus They can use "sudo". I just want to make sure that "unaware" users could not accidentally write/read. I must keep both HDDs on the computer, so as ridgy suggested, only option 1 or 2 would work for me. If I use option 2, can I disable the entire sda <- this is Windows's HDD, or I have to explicitly select all partitions from that drive?

Comment: If it would be OK, that the "unaware" users read but not write the drive, you can mount its partitions read-only via lines in `/etc/fstab`; I think it would be best to address each partition with one line per partition. But alternative 2 by @ridgy is OK too. -- Finally, be aware that an "unaware" user with `sudo` permissions can do 'anything', also modify `/etc/fstab` or simply re-mount the partitions that you want to protect so that they can write to them. **So you need a good backup routine of everything important.**